# PHP + Split paragraph into array

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I cannot find any solution to this. Please help.
I need to split this "paragraph" into sentences array:

> $paragraph = "a. b. c. hello o.c.. hello world -in.. hello. world. 8.5
>   hello world. ";

The resulting array should look like:

```
0=>a.
1=>b.
2=>c.
3=>hell o.c.
4=>hello world -in.
5=>hello.
6=>world.
7=>8.5 hello world.
```

I got this far

```
preg_split('/(?<=[.?!;:])\s+/', $sentence, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

But this does not allow a decimal number.

Comment: Why `hell o.c.`? Your code works as I'd expect it to, https://eval.in/542844, maybe typo on input variable? `$sentence` instead of `$paragraph`...or maybe you are trying to do something else?

Comment: o.c. and -in. are 2 abbreviations that are used in our business that I cannot allow a splitting to occur on.

Comment: How does your current code not work and why `hell o.c.` and not `hello o.c.`? Maybe you need to provide a longer sample string where the issue is more visable?

Comment: Please see this: https://eval.in/542852
I don't want it to split the on the dimensions.

Comment: https://eval.in/542853

0-1 and 5-6 should not be splitting this way.

Comment: Almost. 3-4 should be one sentence:
This sink is drilled for a 8-in. o.c. faucet.

Comment: The example in your question is bad, because your real string contains uppercase letters that can be used to know where to split.

Comment: Perfect chris85. Thank you. Much much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` to tell the regex to not match if the preceding match matches. So

```
(in|o\.c)\.\h+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?<=[.?!])\s+
```

Should tell the regex to not match if `in.` or `o.c.` is matched. Otherwise split on `.`, `!`, or `?` and a space.

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/542856
Regex101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/eS0tR7/1